# Android: Applying an animation to a view creates RuntimeException

Tags: android, animation

I am setting an animation on my view from following the ApiDemo example (see layout_grid_fade.html):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gridLayoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:rowDelay="50%"
        android:directionPriority="column"
        android:animation="@anim/fade" />
```

and below is my code

```
mView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ViewModel.this, R.anim.layout_grid_fade));
mView.setImage(modelImages.get(0).image);
```

but i get exception dont know why? below is my log trace

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown animation name: gridLayoutAnimation
    at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:116)
    at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.createAnimationFromXml(AnimationUtils.java:83)
    at android.view.animation.AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(AnimationUtils.java:64)
    at nick.kimK.ViewModel$1$1.run(ViewModel.java:72)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: its from the link I have provided above

Comment: Ok, the name does look correct. Maybe the file has some control characters in it or needs to be in UTF-8?

Comment: thats not the case all files are correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UPD:
Not every xml in res/anim folder declares an animation. Some of them might declare [Animators](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/animation/Animator.html) or [LayoutAnimationControllers](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html). Those are not Animations, thus they can't be loaded with the `loadAnimation()` call.

--

It looks like the `gridLayoutAnimation` tag describes not a particular basic animation type but rather a [GridLayoutAnimationController](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/animation/GridLayoutAnimationController.html). So it can be loaded directly with AnimationUtils.loadAnimation() but rather should be set to a ViewGroup (a layout) throuh [layoutAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:layoutAnimation) property. If you still want to obtain the AnimationController instance in code, use [AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation()](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationUtils.html#loadLayoutAnimation%28android.content.Context,%20int%29) method:

```
LayoutAnimationController layoutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadLayoutAnimation(ViewModel.this, R.anim.layout_grid_fade)
```

But you hardly can use the layoutAnimation in the way you're doing in your example.
I found [this article](http://www.satyakomatineni.com/akc/display?url=displaynoteimpurl&ownerUserId=satya&reportId=2898) quite useful for understanding the layout animations.

Comment: actually I am using http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/anim/index.html animations from this url some of them work some of them dont

Comment: That's because some of the files do not declare Animations but rather LayoutAnimationControllers (http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html) or Animators (http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/animation/Animator.html).

Comment: means that set of animations can only be used on views that have child element correct me if I am wrong

Comment: That's not a set of animations, that's an animation controller, it is responsible for the time when an animation should be applied etc. In case of LayoutAnimationController, yes, it can be used only with ViewGroups.